# Activate and Deactivate Role using laratrust

Tags: laravel, backend, roles

I'm trying to activate and deactivate role but when deactivate runs i want to check whether the role have users or not if he have users will not deactivate if not will deactivate , and I'M didn't make any relationship between the two model the user model and the role model

this is the deactivate function:

```
  public function deactivate(Role $role)
  {

   $role->update([

         'status' => 'deactivate'
    ]);

    return Response()->json(' deactivated ') 
  }
```

The activate function the same

What I want is when this function runs checks if this role have users or not and I'm using Laratrust for roles

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using the model relationship by using in the Role Model belongsToMany() like this :

```
  public function users()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
   }
```